# Error in my CAML Query? COMException (0x80004005)

Tags: development, error, caml-query

I was wondering if anyone could verify or see an error in this CAML query:

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                            query.Query = string.Format(
                                           "<Where>",
                                            "<Or>",
                                               "<Eq>",
                                                  "<FieldRef Name='ItemRedirectId'/>",
                                                  "<Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value>",
                                               "</Eq>",
                                               "<Eq>",
                                                  "<FieldRef Name='GF_UrlIdRedirection'/>",
                                                  "<Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value>",
                                               "</Eq>",
                                            "</Or>",
                                           "</Where>", RemoveCurlyBracket(RedirectionId));

                            query.ViewFields = string.Empty;
                            query.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
```

I have been getting the System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Cannot complete this action

I have been getting this error in the logs:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Cannot complete this action.
>
> Please try again. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   (0x80004005): Cannot complete this action.
>
> Please try again.    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient
>   pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName,
>   String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags,
>   ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback,
>   ISPDataCallback pPagingPrevCallback, ISPDataCallback
>   pFilterLinkCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback, ISPDataCallback
>   pRowCountCallback, Boolean& pbMaximalView)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient
>   pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName,
>   String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags,
>   ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback,
>   ISPDataCallback pPagingPrevCallback, ISPDataCallback
>   pFilterLinkCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback, ISPDataCallback
>   pRowCountCallback, Boolean& pbMaximalView)    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient
>   pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName,
>   String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags,
>   ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback,
>   ISPDataCallback pPagingPrevCallback, ISPDataCallback
>   pFilterLinkCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback, ISPDataCallback
>   pRowCountCallback, Boolean& pbMaximalView)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.EnsureListItemsData()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.get_Count()

Based on what I was able to find online is that if this was a .net error I would be getting a much more specific answer in terms of what caused the error and that in most cases this error is caused by a bad CAML query, but i cannot find an issue with mine.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a mistake in code. Your string.Format returns only

```
  <where>
```

Try code below

```
query.Query = string.Format(string.Concat(
                                       "<Where>",
                                        "<Or>",
                                           "<Eq>",
                                              "<FieldRef Name='ItemRedirectId'/>",
                                              "<Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value>",
                                           "</Eq>",
                                           "<Eq>",
                                              "<FieldRef Name='GF_UrlIdRedirection'/>",
                                              "<Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value>",
                                           "</Eq>",
                                        "</Or>",
                                       "</Where>"), RemoveCurlyBracket(RedirectionId));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                            query.Query = string.Format(@"<Where>
                                            <Or>
                                               <Eq>
                                                  <FieldRef Name='ItemRedirectId'/>
                                                  <Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value>
                                               </Eq>
                                               <Eq>
                                                  <FieldRef Name='GF_UrlIdRedirection'/>
                                                  <Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value>
                                               </Eq>
                                            </Or>
                                           </Where>", RemoveCurlyBracket(RedirectionId));

                            query.ViewFields = string.Empty;
                            query.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
```

try the above method instead!

its still wrong tho! ill explain! firstly iv used `@` so that you dont use , and you have it witin the `""` allowing you to have multiple lines within the bracket ;). Secondly which i havent ammended is string.Format is used when you want to fill in areas that are varible! as an example:

```
int a = 2;
int b = 2;

string z = string.empty;

z = string.Format(@"a={0} and b={1} which gives an answer of 4",a,b);
```

so `string.Format(text,varible,varible);` , anywhere you put `{0}` is going to be filled up from the varible, i have two in my example `{0}` and `{1}` that get filled by a and b, so the output for z is:

> a=2 and b=2 which gives an answer of 4

another example if i want to expand:

example:

```
int a = 2;
int b = 2;
int c = a * c;
string z = string.empty;

z = string.Format(@"here we are multiplying a and b, so if a={0} and b={1} which gives an answer of {2}",a,b,c);
```

result:

> here we are multiplying a and b, so if a=2 and b=2 which gives an answer of 4

so in your example you have multiple `,` which is not correct and two `{0}` so even if you do use `@` then both `{0}` will be filled from `RemoveCurlyBracket(RedirectionId)` method unless that is what you want??, it should be somthing like this:

```
string itemID = 1;
string UrlIdRedirection = "http://google.com";

SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                            query.Query = string.Format(@"<Where>
                                            <Or>
                                               <Eq>
                                                  <FieldRef Name='ItemRedirectId'/>
                                                  <Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value>
                                               </Eq>
                                               <Eq>
                                                  <FieldRef Name='GF_UrlIdRedirection'/>
                                                  <Value Type='Text'>{1}</Value>
                                               </Eq>
                                            </Or>
                                           </Where>",itemID ,UrlIdRedirection );

                            query.ViewFields = string.Empty;
                            query.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
```

Comment: lol why have i been marked down? this is correct! just becasue the excepted answer uses string.concat which is joing multiple strings of arrays from a comma. either way works!! you need to lookup on what concat does befor marking me down as this is more than a valid answer! the op was using string.Format so i explained why it wasnt working!

Comment: Ali,

I didnt mark you down, i don't know who did, i marked VMAs answer as the correct one since using "@" can and will lead to performance issues. I have read your reply and found it interesting and informative (to some degree) and appreciate the effort you took responding to my inquiry.

Comment: lol i know you didnt, thanks for telling me tho! im just supprised someone marked a valid answer that is correct without expaining why! glad you got your code working tho :)